# How to avoid useless rerender using useReducer([state,dispatch]) and useContext?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using multiple useReducers every component using a part of the state rerenders.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import Store from '../store'
import { setName } from "../actions/nameActions"

const Name = () => {
    const { state: { nameReducer: { name } }, dispatch } = useContext(Store)
    const handleInput = ({ target: { value } }) => { dispatch(setName(value)) }
    console.log('useless rerender if other part (not name) of state is changed'); 
    return <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <input value={name} onChange={handleInput} />
    </div>
}

export default Name;
```

How to avoid this useless rerendering?

Answer (score 16):

If `useState` or `useReducer` state changes, the component is updated, there is no way to prevent this in the component itself.

Re-render should be prevented in child component that depends on partial state, e.g. by making it pure:

```
const NameContainer = () => {
    const { state: { nameReducer: { name } }, dispatch } = useContext(Store)
    return <Name name={name} dispatch={dispatch}/>;
}

const Name = React.memo(({ name, dispatch }) => {
    const handleInput = ({ target: { value } }) => { dispatch(setName(value)) }
    return <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <input value={name} onChange={handleInput} />
    </div>
});
```

`NameContainer` can be rewritten to a HOC and serve the same purpose as Redux `connect`, to extract needed properties from a store and map them to connected component props.

Comment: And why do we need React.memo ?

Comment: Because *Re-render should be prevented in child component that depends on partial state*. React.memo creates pure component.

Comment: So can I state that every functional component that will receive props as data can be wrapped with React.memo()?

Comment: If you don't want a component to be updated when same props are received (usually you don't), React.memo is suitable.

Comment: Can you check my answer below please?

Comment: It's not actually an answer but yes, the problem is that `dispatch` changes every time, https://github.com/nickcoleman/hook-use-combined-reducers/blob/master/src/index.js#L9 . Original useReducer's `dispatch` never changes exactly because it's supposed be passed as a callback. This is a mistake in third-party library you use, open an issue in its repo. You can fix it in NameContainer with `const dispatchThatNeverChanges = useCallback(dispatch, [])`.