# useReducer: dispatch causes rerender even if state is not changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I noticed that if I dispatch an action that happens to not to modify the state, the component is re-rendered anyway.

Example:

```
// for simplicity sake, we simply pass state on (no mutation)
const someReducer = (state, action) => state

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(someReducer, 0)

  // in my use case, I want to dispatch an action if some specific condition in state occurs
  if(state === 0) {
    dispatch({ type: 'SOME ACTION' })  // type doesn't matter
  }
  // return some JSX
}
```

I get:

```
Error in app.js (16929:26)
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Is this by design? Should it be this way?

Comment: You are never changing the state, thus `if(state === 0) {` is always true causing an infinite loop. Dispatching in this case will basically trigger `setState` which always cause a re-render (unless you override shouldComponentUpdate).

Comment: @TiagoHenriqueEngel that's what I'm asking about - why is it re-rendered (and dispatch is called again), if state has not changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of your example as-is, it's not immediately obvious as to what is causing the component to re-render. However, the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-dispatch) seem to suggest that it's not a guarantee that a re-render won't occur when you don't mutate the state:

> **Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out.** That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

This is why it's generally recommended that you run code that potentially has side effects in `useEffect` e.g.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(someReducer, 0);
...
useEffect(() => {
  if (state === 0) {
    dispatch({ type: 'SOME ACTION' });
  }
}, [state]);
```

Comment: or make pure function as suggested here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368252/how-to-avoid-useless-rerender-using-usereducerstate-dispatch-and-usecontext?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ChotalaParesh yep, possibly, depending on what is actually being rendered (the OP doesn't offer that information).

Comment: Interesting... Could it be that React simply assumes that a reducer is meant to mutate state, so state change checks are simply not performed and therefore the component gets re-rendered? What other purpose could a reducer have other than changing state?

Comment: @tiguchi I'd be surprised if that were the case

Comment: Won't this case create another infinite loop?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro in what way?

Comment: It depends on the `state` value